# Why does my app crash when I change my namespace?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I'm following the material given in the book *Easy Laravel 5* to learn Laravel. So I created the app as directed, and when I visited `localhost:8000`, I saw the welcome page.

Then I gave the name change command:

```
php artisan app:name todoparrot
```

To which the system responded with `Application namespace set!`. But now when I reload `localhost:8000`, I see nothing, and the terminal serving the app gives me a long list of errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class todoparrot\Console\Kernel does not exist' in /media/common/htdocs/todoparrot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:776
Stack trace:
#0 /media/common/htdocs/todoparrot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(776): ReflectionClass->__construct('todoparrot\Cons...')
#1 /media/common/htdocs/todoparrot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(656): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('todoparrot\Cons...', Array)
#2 /media/common/htdocs/todoparrot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(613): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('todoparrot\Cons...', Array)
#3 /media/common/htdocs/todoparrot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(229): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('todoparrot\Cons...', Array)
#4 /media/common/htdocs/todoparrot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(773): Illuminate\Container\Con in /media/common/htdocs/todoparrot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 776
```

Now I'm not able to even run `artisan`, as I keep getting the same error. Any idea what might be broken because of this extremely simple change?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this command after renaming:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Composer has autoload files at `vendor/composer/` directory with your namespaces. when you change any you need to clear it and generate it again, and that command does it.

Comment: @dotslash composer has autoload files at `vendor/composer/` directory with your namespaces. when you change any you need to clear it and generate it again, and that command does it.

Comment: For me, it was in particular in the file `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` that needed the extra line `'todoparrot\\' => array($baseDir . '/app'),` in the array (`todoparrot` being the new name of the app).

Answer (score 1):

If you run command below, it will change all the namespace and path to todoparrot. In your case Laravel not found "Class todoparrot\Console\Kernel does not exist". Make sure the namespace was changed to todoparrot

```
php artisan app:name todoparrot
```

The command will modify all the files below

```
modified:   app/Commands/Command.php
modified:   app/Console/Commands/Inspire.php
modified:   app/Console/Kernel.php
modified:   app/Events/Event.php
modified:   app/Exceptions/Handler.php
modified:   app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php
modified:   app/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php
modified:   app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php
modified:   app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
modified:   app/Http/Controllers/WelcomeController.php
modified:   app/Http/Kernel.php
modified:   app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php
modified:   app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
modified:   app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
modified:   app/Http/Requests/Request.php
modified:   app/Http/routes.php
modified:   app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
modified:   app/Providers/BusServiceProvider.php
modified:   app/Providers/ConfigServiceProvider.php
modified:   app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
modified:   app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
modified:   app/Services/Registrar.php
modified:   bootstrap/app.php
modified:   composer.json
modified:   config/app.php
modified:   config/auth.php
```

Example in app/Console/Kernel.php the command will change this

```
namespace App\Console;

protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\Inspire',
];
```

To

```
namespace todoparrot\Console;

protected $commands = [
    'todoparrot\Console\Commands\Inspire',
];
```

Please check file app/Console/Kernel.php if "App\" path still available. If available please change to "todoparrot\".

I already try run command "php artisan app:name todoparrot". It not have any problem. I don't know why it will thrown error at yours.

Comment: I did a fresh app install, changed the name to `parrot` and still the problem persists for me. :( The biggest surprise is that my Kernel.php shows everything to be setup properly: http://pastebin.com/CW5wqLr0

Answer (score -1):

Ggo to C:\wamp\www\laravel\ in the command prompt use

```
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer dump-autoload
```

instead of

```
composer dump-autoload
```